# database design of a family and how to insert into database

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop

I am still new in programming as this is my 1st year in programming field. I have read few other post about designing family tree in here but i still didn't understand some details so i need your help. by the way, i use PHP

this is my simplified version form

```
// family leader
<div id="family_leader">
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="text" name="ic[]"> // ic is the same like SSN
</div>

// family member
// here input wife or child info
// i use javascript to clone the div so user can add how many family member they have.
<div id="family_member">
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="number" name="ic[]"> 
    <input type="text" name="relationship[]">
</div>
```

and i'm thinking of making a database this way

1st table will be like this

**User table**

```
+--------+--------------+--------------+ 
|   id   |     name     |      ic      |
+--------+--------------+--------------+
| id1    | John         | 9357906268   | 
+--------+--------------+--------------+
| id2    | Josh         | 9357222228   | 
+--------+--------------+--------------+
```

and i will have another table for their relationship

**Relationship table**

- no one is a father/mother to Josh
- Josh is a father to john

the table will look like this

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|  owner_id   |  family_id   | relationship |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|   ic1/id1   |   ic2/id2    |   father     | 
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
|   ic2/id2   |   ic1/id1    |   child      | 
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

i make it this way in case of single parent and i want to make this data viewable in a profile

its like

husband has 1 wife
father has 1 or many child
child has 1 father

so far this is what i got

**family class**

```
<?php 
/**
* this is my family class
*/
class Family 
{

    function __construct(argument)
    {
        # database construct here
    }

    public function getUser($_POST)
    {
        foreach ($_POST['name'] as $row) {
            # this is how im going to insert the data of user into user table
            $sql1="INSERT INTO User ( name, ic) values (" $_POST[name][i]", "$_POST[ic][i]")" // e.g John, 9357906268 
        }
    }

    public function getRelation($_POST)
    {
        $sql2="INSERT INTO Relationship ( owner_id, family_id, relationship) values ( $_POST['ic'][i], $_POST['ic'][1], $_POST['relationship'][i])"

        /**
        * this is where my problem reside
        * i don't know how to make this function
        */
    }
}
```

so how do i insert correctly into the 2nd table?

i'm also thinking of doing a switch case inside the getRelation

```
switch ($_POST['relation']) {
    case 'father':
        // in here is if Josh is a father to John then John is a child to Josh.
        break;

    case 'mother':
        # code...
        break;

    // ... more case

    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
```

or maybe create more function in the class?

```
 public function isFather($value='')
{
    # code...
}

public function isMother($value='')
{
    #
}
```

the problem is i am not sure how to do the logic inside the function or switch case to determine the relationship of the users.

and is this the correct way of database design and OOP?

thank you for your time .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and is this the correct way of database design?

Small fixes: define Primary Key in `User` and use it in `Relations.owner_id` and `Relations.family_id`. Add FOREIGN KEY constraints on those 2 columns.

Also maybe you need to store the gender of the user as it may happen the family_leader is actually mother.

Storing `Relations.relationship` as a string may give performance problem if you have millions of records but for a learning task it is ok. In MySQL there is a [CHECK Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_check.asp) that can be used to limit the field values to some fixed list of strings e.g. `CHECK relationship IN('father', 'son', 'daughter','wife','husband')`.

Before answering the next question I want to note a minor problem in your HTML code:

> this is my simplified version form

You are mixing here the family_leader and family_member.  It is better separate them:

```
<div id="family_leader">
    <input type="text" name="family_leader[name]">
    <input type="text" name="family_leader[ic]"> // ic is the same like SSN
</div>

<div class="family_member"> <!-- don't use id if you're gonna duplicate this div -->
    <input type="text" name="name[]">
    <input type="number" name="ic[]"> 
    <input type="text" name="relationship[]"> <!-- consider using <select> tag here to limit possible relationhips -->
</div>
```

> and OOP?

A small note: using `getUser` and `getRelation` isn't good. "Get" means you're retrieving data from somewhere without changing. When your function inserts the data you should name it `saveUser` (and `saveRelation`).

Now you asked:

> the problem is i am not sure how to do the logic inside the function
>   or switch case to determine the relationship of the users.

I would recommend following OOP approach: create the following `User` class:

```
<?php

class User {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $ic;

    public function save() {
        // save the user to the db and update $this->id with autogenerated id
    }

    public function addChild(User $child) {
        // add to `Relations`: [$this->id, $child->id, 'father']
        // then add to `Relations`: [$child->id, $this->id, 'child']
    }

    public function addWife(User $wife) {
        // check if  this user already has a wife and throw an Exception "Wife already exists"
        // 
        // add to `Relations`: [$this->id, $wife->id, 'husband']
        // then add to `Relations`: [$wife->id, $this->id, 'wife']
    }

    public function addRelative($relationship, User $relative) {
        switch ($relationship) {
            case 'child':
                $this->addChild($relative);
                break;

            case 'wife':
                $this->addWife($relative);
                break;

            default:
                throw new Exception("Unknown relationship:" . $relationship);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

then in the `Family` class use following function:

```
public function saveFamily() {
    $family_leader = new User()
    $family_leader->name = $_POST['family_leader']['name'];
    $family_leader->ic = $_POST['family_leader']['ic'];
    $family_leader->save();

    foreach ($_POST['name'] as $i => $name) {
        $family_member = new User();
        $family_member->name = $name;
        $family_member->ic = $_POST['ic'][$i];
        $family_member->save();

        try {
            $family_leader->addRelative($_POST['relationship']['$i'], $family_member);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            die ('Relationship not added:' . $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do i use the family class this way? `$family = new family();
 $family = saveFamily();` will the class get the $_POST?

Comment: Define `saveFamily()` inside `Family` class and use `$family = new Family(); $family->saveFamily();` In future you may look for some nice techniques like [method chaining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining#PHP)

Comment: you think can i update my question with what i have done so far?i think there is something wrong with my user class

Comment: It's better to ask the new question and include the code for only the problematic portion. This question already includes too many topics and is on the verge of being marked as "too broad"

Comment: ya that's what i tought too as your answer already answered my current question.

Comment: or is there some way here i can show u my code? i think function for addchild and addwife might be the problem

Comment: oh.. its ok XD i fix it .its working now.i jst forgot to put method="post" in my <form> i always make silly mistake like this.